# continuity and differentiable equivalent to 0

Tags: continuity

[image]

This is how I have the proof for this set up.  However now I'm not really sure that saying "f'(x)=(f(1)-0)/1=f(1).  This is equivalent to f'(x)=f(b).  Hence we can write that f'(x)≥f(x)." is the right route to go?  Does this look like the right direction?

Comment: MVT is certainly a good idea. But the rest is ... not so compelling. Especially, "Therefore $0\le f'(x)\le 2 f(x)$" makes little sense when that is in fact a *given* property of $f$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $f$ attains it maximum on the closed interval $[0,\frac12]$ at some $x_0\in [0,\frac12]$. Assume $f(x_0)>0$ and invoke the IVT to find $0<\xi<x_0$ with $f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x_0)-f(0)}{x_0-0}> 2 f(x_0)$ and use that $2f(\xi)\ge f'(\xi)$. From this you obtgain a contradiction and hence  deduce that $f(x)=0$ for $0\le x\le\frac13$. How can you proceed to the rest of the interval?

Comment: im going to have to think on that lol.  will have to look at the IVT theorem more.  Makes sense, just not 100% sure on how to work it out yet.  So you are saying to ditch the idea of MVT totally?

Comment: Rolle's Theorem states If f is differentiable on [a, b], then between any two zeroes of f there must be a zero of its derivative f

Comment: ugh!  I SEE it.. Its like right there lol. /sigh I need to not think about this problem for a bit

Comment: okay to proceed to the rest of the interval I deal with finding the minimum?

Comment: But why even split it, wouldn't it be easier to take from [0,1]?

Answer (score 0):

Okay looking at the theorems and some stuff similar this is what I am coming up with now. I feel this might make more sense of the proof? [image]